# Change Data Feed not working in delta live tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

When I'm trying to see change data feed changes by applying alter table set delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true.
Property was enabled but i couldn't see any changes.

I'm getting error like there are no changes

I have set Property is true  but i couldn't see any changes

Answer (score 0):

When you switch Change Data Feed on, the changes are collected only from the next version after you did the change. If you will try to call `table_changes` using earlier version, then it will generate an error.

It's [described in the docs](https://docs.delta.io/2.0.0/delta-change-data-feed.html#enable-change-data-feed), in the section marked as "Important!":

> Only changes made after you enable the change data feed are recorded; past changes to a table are not captured.